# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" for package

Tags: sql, oracle, package

I have to execute a SQL file (I do not have much idea of SQL, I just have to execute it) but there is an error I do not understand:

> Errors: check compiler log
>   Errors for PACKAGE USER1.TST_MAI_FILTER:
>   LINE/COL ERROR
>
> ---
>
> 29/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

This is the PACKAGE USER1.TST_MAI_FILTER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TST_MAI_FILTER IS

FUNCTION TRADE_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER;

FUNCTION ORDER_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER;

FUNCTION MRKT_EVT_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER;

FUNCTION DAILY_DATA_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER;

PROCEDURE log_mai_filter(p_run_id NUMBER, p_config_id NUMBER);

PROCEDURE is_valid_filter
(p_mai_class_id IN NUMBER,
 p_type_id IN NUMBER,
 v_where  CLOB);

END TST_MAI_FILTER;
/
```

I am using Oracle SQL Developer (Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production).

EDIT: This is line 29:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE S_TRD START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER;
```

and this is the rest of the package but it does not get until there since the developer stops after this error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TST_MAI_FILTER IS

FUNCTION TRADE_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER
IS    
BEGIN
RETURN 1;
END;

FUNCTION ORDER_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER
IS    
BEGIN
RETURN 2;
END;

FUNCTION MRKT_EVT_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER
IS    
BEGIN
RETURN 3;
END;

FUNCTION DAILY_DATA_TYPE
RETURN NUMBER
IS    
BEGIN
RETURN 4;
END;


PROCEDURE log_mai_filter(p_run_id NUMBER, p_config_id NUMBER)
IS
v_mesg  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) := NULL;
BEGIN

INSERT INTO mai_filter_log (run_id, mai_query_id, sql_query, config_id, type_id, mai_class_id)
SELECT p_run_id, mai_query_id, sql_query,  config_id, type_id, mai_class_id
FROM mai_filter
WHERE config_id = p_config_id;        

LOG_INFO(p_run_id, 'I', 'RUN_LOG: Log mai_filter: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT );

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_mesg := 'An error has occured when executing log_mai_filter - ' || SQLCODE || ' -ERROR- ' || SQLERRM;
    raise_application_error(-20085, v_mesg);
    LOG_INFO(p_run_id, 'E', v_mesg); 
END;

PROCEDURE is_valid_filter
(p_mai_class_id IN NUMBER,
 p_type_id IN NUMBER,
 v_where  CLOB) IS 
v_tbl VARCHAR2(400 BYTE) := NULL;
BEGIN
SELECT type_name INTO v_tbl
FROM mai_filter_type
WHERE type_id = p_type_id;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT run_id FROM ' || v_tbl || ' WHERE run_id = 0 AND '|| v_where;    

END;

END TST_MAI_FILTER;
/
```

Comment: thats just a spec of a package. what is on line 29? do you execute it in a SQL window?

Comment: How are you executing the file, and what else does it contain?

Comment: I just open it via Oracle SQL Developer and let it run. I have edited the question.

Comment: @AlexPoole it is a very big file, I can't copy all of it here.

Comment: So the script starts with the `CREATE PACKAGE` (lines 1-23), then `CREATE SEQUENCE` at line 29, then the package body?

Comment: try to create a sequence before you create a spac of package. not between spec and body

Comment: The script starts with creating sequences, then creating tables, then altering tables, then insert datas and at the ende there are create procedures, functions, triggers and packages

Comment: The line 29 in the error message refers to line 29 of that package spec, not of the script. You've only shown 23 lines for that, so something doesn't add up. Are you sure your script actually has the `/` between the package spec and body, and you haven't just added that to the question automatically? That's the only way I can see that error being generated (and there would swill need to be blank lines or a comment between them, to make the numbers work.)